# Is it possible to require raw files with angular browser-esbuild like in webpack?

Tags: angular, esbuild

In Webpack we can use a raw-loader to load a file like that:

```
require('!!rawloader!./yourfile.html').default
```

I'd like to do the same in Angular with the experimental browser-esbuild builder. With normal esbuild I could write a plugin or use it but how can I do it in the Angular esbuild implementation?

Comment: Hi, have you found the browser-esbuild alternative/workaround?